# C# uwp client server show components

Tags: c#, uwp, client, visibility

I have a problem with my server uwp side.

I try do unhide some components like this but my app hangs on :

```
private async void StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    string request;
    using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
    {
        request = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
    }
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.txtBlk_Events.Text = request);

    if (request.Length > 0)
    {
        btnSend.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

It is possible to do that or not ?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Where exactly does it hang?

Comment: on : btnSend.Visibility = Visibility.Visible ; If i comment this line, the server keep alive,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Visibility` is a UI property and must be set on the UI thread. In your case it will run on the same thread the `ConnectionReceived` event handler is run on (thanks to `async/await`) which is likely not the UI thread. You should instead set the `Visibility` within the `Dispatcher.RunAsync` call to make sure it runs on UI thread.

```
private async void StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    string request;
    using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
    {
        request = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
    }

    var setVisibility = request.Length > 0;

    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
    {
       this.txtBlk_Events.Text = request;
       if ( setVisibility )
       {
          btnSend.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
       }
    });              
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help and explication.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved